# What do i need to do to "while loop" stop?

Tags: php, while-loop, readline

I want to check if the user enters a number between 1-10, if he does, the program should proceed, if not the program should prompt him to reenter. here's my code (php)

```
$good = false;
   while ($good == false){
   $guess = readline(">>");
   $guess = intval($guess);
   if($guess == 1 or $guess == 2 or $guess == 3 or $guess == 4 or $guess == 5 or $guess == 6 or $guess == 7 or $guess == 8 or $guess == 9 or $guess == 10){
     $guess = true;
   }else{
    echo "Invalid number. Please try again.\n";
     $guess == false; 
   }
     }
```

it continues to loop even if the user enter a number between 1-10. I've tried to debug with no success. any suggestions?

Comment: You are not modifying `$good` inside the loop, due to which the loop goes on infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update $guess instead of $good.
According to your loop, $guess will never be updated to true and it will always be false.
So, your loop will continue anyway.

You should update $good to `false` once your condition is met and this will stop the loop.

One more thing is you should use php [in_array()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp) function rather than comparing $guess variable against 1 to 10.

You should check like this:

```
    if (in_array($guess, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])){
    // your code here
}
```

or even like this:

```
$accepted_numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

if (in_array($guess, $accepted_numbers)){
    // your code here
}
```

See code below:

```
$accepted_numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

    if (in_array($guess, $accepted_numbers)){
             // $guess = true;
             $good = true; // you should update $good to true

           }else{
            echo "Invalid number. Please try again.\n";
              // $guess == false; (you don't need this) 
           }
```